# Есть ли смысл записывать html элементы в const если часто к ним обращаешься?

Tags: javascript, html

Если есть какие-то элементы в `html` которые будут постоянно меняться, например по кнопке. Есть ли смысл сохранять их в `const` или лучше каждый раз получать их через `document.getElementById`?

Например такие элементы:

```
<button id="btn">Изменить</button>

<div id="element1">
  <p>Какой-то текст</p>
</div>

<div id="element2">
  <p>Совершенно другой текст</p>
  <div>Рандомный див</div>
</div>

<div id="element3">
  <p>Третий текст</p>
  <p>Третий текст часть 2</p>
</div>
```

И они не будут задействованы лишь однажды, к ним придётся постоянно обращаться чтобы то фон им сменить, то ещё что... Н
Как лучше подходить к этим элементам? Записывать ли их в `const`? Например, так:

```
const el1 = document.getElementById('element1')
const el2 = document.getElementById('element2')
const el3 = document.getElementById('element3')

function hoverActions() {
    el1.style.backgroundColor = "red"
    el2.style.backgroundColor = "green"
    el3.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
}
```

Или так:

```
function hoverActions() {
    document.getElementById('element1').style.backgroundColor = "red"
    document.getElementById('element2').style.backgroundColor = "green"
    document.getElementById('element3').style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
}
```

Comment: "если часто к ним обращаешься"  то да, имеет смысл в переменную выделить элемент

Answer (score 0):

Смысл однозначно есть, это намного удобнее, если этот объект когда-либо понадобится ещё то не придётся писать огромное document.getElementById снова, а это экономит драгоценные силы на написание кода

Советую объявлять const-ы таким способом, если их много, чтобы занимать меньше места

```
const 
    a = getElementById('a'),
    b = getElementById('b'),
    c = getElementById('c')
```

Comment: Я бы не советовал так объявлять)  во-первых строка с тем что будут константы и перечисление на другой строке - уже не по одному из стандарту (если только будет принято в узком кругу спецов на работе), и поэтому в других кругах не поймут. во-вторых, если удалить последний элемент и забыть убрать запятую у предпоследнего - будет ошибка......... проще всё объявлять на отдельной строке `const myVar = myValue;`

Comment: Спасибо, я не знал что существуют такие стандарты для кода, просто всегда думал что так будет проще объявлять переменные и константы